# JNI: map jobject to native c++ object

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I use regular std::map to map jobject's to c++ objects. The problem with this approach is that it may fail for other types of references, e.g. global references are actually different pointer than regular local references even if they reference the same object. The correct way to compare if two references reference the same object is:

```
env->IsSameObject(jobj1, jobj2);
```

So, my question is: what's the correct way to map jobject's to c++ objects? The obvious reply to wrap jobject into some c++ class that overloads operator== and calls IsSameObject isn't the reply that I'm looking for. I'd like to know if there is way to do it without going back and forth between JVM and native c/c++ for every compare operation.

**EDIT:** global reference is a jni global reference, and has nothing to do with c++ references.

**EDIT2:** I'd like to clarify what the problem is with this code:

```
std::map<jobject, void *> jobjs;
jobject obj1, obj2;
... some code that sets these obj1 and obj2 to some Java objects.

jobjs[obj1] = new CppPeer;
CppPeer * = jobjs[obj1]; //OK...
if(objs.find(obj2) == objs.end()){
   assert(obj2 != obj1);
   //Here's the problem: here a new c++ CppPeer
   //created for obj2, but the problem is that 
   //even if obj1 != ob2 it doesn't mean that
   //they actually reference different java objects
   //On the next line error might happen
   jobjs[obj2] = new CppPeer; //maybe not OK here...
}
```

The other problem with IsSameObject is that it makes things pretty nasty and messy. Not only now I'd need to keep a pointer to JVM, but also whenever I need to compare jobjects I'd need to attach thread etc to get pointer to JNIEnv to be able to check jobject

**EDIT3:** Be aware, that according to android docs you cannot even assume that two references reference the same object if they are equal. I don't know how it's possible, but there's the part from Android's JNI tips page:

> One consequence of this is that you must not assume object references
>   are constant or unique in native code. The 32-bit value representing
>   an object may be different from one invocation of a method to the
>   next, and **it's possible that two different objects could have the same
>   32-bit value on consecutive calls. Do not use jobject values as keys**.

Comment: @MooingDuck: perhaps I missed new c++ things like unique_ptr, but I don't think that regular c++ tricks will cover the problem. The problem is JNI specific, e.g. solution should about some kind of JNI function call, not c/c++ trick.

Comment: I think you didn't get the point. It has nothing to do with lifetime of a c++ object. E.g. I don't need unique_ptr (or, in other words, it's unrelated to the question). With JNI multiple jobjects might actually be pointers to the same java object (jobject is a typedef for a void*). The only way to check that some jobject is the same is to use IsSameObject and i'd like to know if there is way around. Also, it has nothing to do with map also. Simply when I have MANY jni objects and c++ peers then map search would need to make too many calls to JVM to compare pointers. That's the point.

Comment: I added a couple of edits to the original question. In short it has nothing to do with maps or ptr wrappers, it's really about JNI only.

Comment: Ah, so the problem is, given a `jobject a`, and list `b` of `jobjects`, you need to find out if `a` refers to the same Java object as anything in `b`.  I get it.  That explains the confusion.  Deleting my half-written answer...

Comment: Yes, that's the point. To reliably check equality of two jobjects is to call IsSameObject but it's not that easy, because to get required env pointer there is some nasty bookkeeping required, so that's the point of the question.

Comment: I really can't think of anything besides looping through the entire map and calling `IsSameObject` on each key...

Comment: Yes, it seems to be the only way (unless there is a special JNI trick for that), but implementing this loop with IsSameObject is really not that simple if you actually try to do it. It's all because it need to have pointer to JNIEnv for which you need to attach to JVM etc (you can't store pointers to JNIEnv), gets quite messy this thing overall...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DISCLAIMER: it smells.

On Android, pointer and `jint` are of the same size. Consider adding an int field to your Java class to store a pointer to the native conterpart. When in a JNI method, typecast it back to a pointer.

To be on a slightly safer side, do a static assert on datatype matching:

```
{char a[sizeof(void*) == sizeof(jint) ? 1 : -1]};
```

If it's compiled on a system where it's not, you'll get a compilation error.

For slightly less smell, use a static/global `map` from int to your objects, use an ID generator, and instead of object pointer store relatively unique (within process lifetime) objects IDs within the Java object.

Comment: Even though it doesn't answer the original question, I agree this is an alternative solution that actually avoids that problem. I don't care for the smell (java's smell beats it anyways), the only drawback is that it requires changes in java code and methods signature changes all over the place.